# How can I convert an FFmpeg AVFrame with pixel format AV_PIX_FMT_CUDA to a new AVFrame with pixel format AV_PIX_FMT_RGB

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, h.264, cuvid

I have a simple C++ application that uses FFmpeg 3.2 to receive an H264 RTP stream. In order to save CPU, I'm doing the decoding part with the codec h264_cuvid. My FFmpeg 3.2 is compiled with hw acceleration enabled. In fact, if I do the command:

```
ffmpeg -hwaccels
```

I get

```
cuvid
```

This means that my FFmpeg setup has everything OK to "speak" with my NVIDIA card.
The frames that the function `avcodec_decode_video2` provides me have the pixel format `AV_PIX_FMT_CUDA`. I need to convert those frames to new ones with `AV_PIX_FMT_RGB`. Unfortunately, I can't do the conversion using the well knwon functions `sws_getContext` and `sws_scale` because the pixel format `AV_PIX_FMT_CUDA` is not supported. If I try with swscale I get the error:

"cuda is not supported as input pixel format"

Do you know how to convert an FFmpeg `AVFrame` from `AV_PIX_FMT_CUDA` to `AV_PIX_FMT_RGB` ?
(pieces of code would be very appreciated)

Comment: If all u need is to decode with cuvid, I guess there is no need to deal with AV_PIX_FMT_CUDA. Though there is no example about this, `qsvdec.c` and `hw_decode.c` official example could be a good reference. And the decoder should return nv12 format to host memory here.

Answer (score 8):

This my understanding of the hardware decoding on the latest FFMPeg 4.1 version. Below are my conclusion after studying the source code.

First I recommend to inspire yourself from the hw_decode example:

https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/release/4.1/doc/examples/hw_decode.c

With the new API, when you send a packet to the encoder using [avcodec_send_packet()](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/4.1/group__lavc__decoding.html#ga58bc4bf1e0ac59e27362597e467efff3), then use [avcodec_receive_frame()](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/4.1/group__lavc__decoding.html#ga11e6542c4e66d3028668788a1a74217c) to retrieve the decoded frame.

There are two different kinds of `AVFrame`: *software* one, which is stored in the "CPU" memory (a.k.a RAM), and *hardware* one, which is stored in the graphic card memory.

### Getting AVFrame from the hardware

To retrieve the hardware frame and get it into a readable, convertible (with swscaler) `AVFrame`, [av_hwframe_transfer_data()](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/4.1/hwcontext_8c.html#abf1b1664b8239d953ae2cac8b643815a) needs to be used to retrieve the data from the graphic card. Then look at the pixel format of the retrieved frame, it is usually NV12 format when using nVidia decoding.

```
// According to the API, if the format of the AVFrame is set before calling 
// av_hwframe_transfer_data(), the graphic card will try to automatically convert
// to the desired format. (with some limitation, see below)
m_swFrame->format = AV_PIX_FMT_NV12;

// retrieve data from GPU to CPU
err = av_hwframe_transfer_data(
     m_swFrame, // The frame that will contain the usable data.
     m_decodedFrame, // Frame returned by avcodec_receive_frame()
     0);

const char* gpu_pixfmt = av_get_pix_fmt_name((AVPixelFormat)m_decodedFrame->format);
const char* cpu_pixfmt = av_get_pix_fmt_name((AVPixelFormat)m_swFrame->format);
```

### Listing supported "software" pixel formats

Side note here if you want to select the pixel format, not all AVPixelFormat are supported. [AVHWFramesConstraints](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/4.1/structAVHWFramesConstraints.html) is your friend here:

```
AVHWDeviceType type = AV_HWDEVICE_TYPE_CUDA;
int err = av_hwdevice_ctx_create(&hwDeviceCtx, type, nullptr, nullptr, 0);
if (err < 0) {
    // Err
}

AVHWFramesConstraints* hw_frames_const = av_hwdevice_get_hwframe_constraints(hwDeviceCtx, nullptr);
if (hw_frames_const == nullptr) {
    // Err
}

// Check if we can convert the pixel format to a readable format.
AVPixelFormat found = AV_PIX_FMT_NONE;
for (AVPixelFormat* p = hw_frames_const->valid_sw_formats; 
    *p != AV_PIX_FMT_NONE; p++)
{
    // Check if we can convert to the desired format.
    if (sws_isSupportedInput(*p))
    {
        // Ok! This format can be used with swscale!
        found = *p;
        break;
    }
}

// Don't forget to free the constraint object.
av_hwframe_constraints_free(&hw_frames_const);

// Attach your hw device to your codec context if you want to use hw decoding.
// Check AVCodecContext.hw_device_ctx!
```

Finally, a quicker way is probably the [av_hwframe_transfer_get_formats()](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/4.1/hwcontext_8c.html#a2467bc6d78356f81f74d9acf6cc1f2d7) function, but you need to decode at least one frame.

Hope this will help!

Comment: Excuse me, I notice the decoding and encoding are run on the nvidia gpu via cuda. But **the conversion of pixel format is run on CPU**, which is astonishingly CPU consuming. So could you provide some methods to convert pixel format from `nv12` to `rgb` on GPU?

Answer (score 2):

You must use `vf_scale_npp` to do this. You can use either `nppscale_deinterleave` or `nppscale_resize` depend on your needs.

Both has same input parameters, which are [AVFilterContext](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.2/structAVFilterContext.html) that should be initialize with `nppscale_init`, [NPPScaleStageContext](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.2/structNPPScaleStageContext.html) which takes your in/out pixel format and two [AVFrame](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.2/structAVFrame.html)s which of course are your input and output frames.

For more information you can see [npplib\nppscale](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.2/vf__scale__npp_8c_source.html) definition which will do the CUDA-accelerated format conversion and scaling since ffmpeg 3.1.

Anyway, I recommend to use [NVIDIA Video Codec SDK](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-video-codec-sdk) directly for this purpose.

Comment: Hi Hamed. Thanks a lot for your answer. I'm going to study that vf_scale_npp. The functions 

static int nppscale_deinterleave (AVFilterContext *ctx, NPPScaleStageContext * stage, AVFrame *out, AVFrame *in);

static int nppscale_resize (AVFilterContext *ctx, NPPScaleStageContext * stage, AVFrame *out, AVFrame *in);

seem really well promising. I'll give me feedback soon. thanks again

Comment: Hi Hamed. I tried, but with no success.
I get success from the function "nppscale_init" but failure from "nppscale_deinterleave". From this last I get the error code:

[in @ 0x7fff69b97820] NPP deinterleave error: -8

Apparently the problem is in my "in" AVFrame. But what ? Do you know what it means it ? You also suggested to use the NVIDIA Video Codec SDK directly for such conversions. I'm willing to use it. FFmpeg lacks of documentation and good examples here. Do you have a piece of code, a function maybe, that receives an AVFrame got from cuvid and returns a new one in AV_PIX_FMT_RGB ?

Comment: Ok, no problem. Thanks anyway
I've investigated deeper. I saw that "nppscale_deinterleave" calls the "nppiYCbCr420_8u_P2P3R" function
and it returns the error code -8. That error code is 

NPP_NULL_POINTER_ERROR = -8

I've checked that I don't pass any NULL to "nppscale_deinterleave", but the error still occurs. I suspect that I've to "bring" more code of that vf_scale_npp in my software.

Answer (score 2):

I am not an ffmpeg expert, but I had a similar problem and managed to solve it. I was getting `AV_PIX_FMT_NV12` from cuvid (mjpeg_cuvid decoder), and wanted `AV_PIX_FMT_CUDA` for cuda processing.

I found that setting the pixel format just before decoding the frame worked.

```
    pCodecCtx->pix_fmt = AV_PIX_FMT_CUDA; // change format here
    avcodec_decode_video2(pCodecCtx, pFrame, &frameFinished, &packet);
    // do something with pFrame->data[0] (Y) and pFrame->data[1] (UV)
```

You can check which pixel formats are supported by your decoder using pix_fmts:

```
    AVCodec *pCodec = avcodec_find_decoder_by_name("mjpeg_cuvid");
    for (int i = 0; pCodec->pix_fmts[i] != AV_PIX_FMT_NONE; i++)
            std::cout << pCodec->pix_fmts[i] << std::endl;
```

I'm sure there's a better way of doing this, but I then used [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/unosquare/ffplaydotnet/master/Unosquare.FFplayDotNet/FFmpeg/FFmpeg.enums.g.cs) list to map the integer pixel format ids to human readable pixel formats.

If that doesn't work, you can do a cudaMemcpy to transfer your pixels from device to host:

```
    cudaMemcpy(pLocalBuf pFrame->data[0], size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
```

The conversion from YUV to RGB/RGBA can be done many ways. [This example](http://hasanaga.info/how-to-capture-frame-from-webcam-witg-ffmpeg-api-and-display-image-with-opencv/) does it using the libavdevice API.